# Elementor Popup need close and do not show again by javascript

Tags: javascript, elementor

I already have code that closes Elementor 2 popup by one button, but can't make save it in cookie sessions to not show a second time when site loading, this is for cookie police popup.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.close-popup', function( event ) {
        $( "#elementor-popup-modal-4874 .dialog-close-button" ).click();
        $( "#elementor-popup-modal-4877 .dialog-close-button" ).click();
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 You can try this
 

    
var subsc_cookie = $.cookie('emailSubcribeModal'); 
     if(subsc_cookie != 'closed'){ 
         $( "#elementor-popup-modal-4874 .dialog-close-button" ).show();
        $( "#elementor-popup-modal-4877 .dialog-close-button" ).show();
     }
   
     $('.close-popup').on('click', function(){
        $( "#elementor-popup-modal-4874 .dialog-close-button" ).hide();
        $( "#elementor-popup-modal-4877 .dialog-close-button" ).hide();
             document.cookie = "emailSubcribeModal=closed;"; 
             setCookie("emailSubcribeModal", "closed", 3 );
     })
```